# vertical align weird behaviour with form input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was playing with bootstrap form elements and noticed that input type text's vertical align property somehow affects positioning of the nearby label.

By the way this input type text has margin-bottom 10px that comes from bootstrap styling.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <style>
        input[type="text"] {
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <span>Name</span>
        <input id="name" type="text">     
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I set:

```
        input[type="text"] {
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }
```

I get normal positioning:

[image]

But when I set :

```
        input[type="text"] {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

I was expecting to see that input element would be positioned but insted label element changed its location

[image]

And when I set :

```
        input[type="text"] {
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }
```

I see again positioning being applied to the label element:

[image]

I was always thinking that smth like this will happen:

body element will define line-height of the line box in which both label and input elements are sitting. After that both label and input elements will be positioned according to their vertical-align property with respect the line box defined by body element.

But here I see that somehow chaging vertical align property of the input element affects label element. Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem becomes clearer if you remove all the other elements from the screen.

With the default setting of `vertical-align:baseline`, the baseline of the input gets aligned to the baseline to the span. I've made the outline of the elements red, and the y coordinate of where they align blue. Then this is what the line box looks like when you leave the vertical alignment to the default.

[image: vertical-align:baseline]

Now whether you align the two elements to the top

[image: vertical-align:top]

or to the bottom

[image: vertical-align:bottom]

the general layout remains the same. Since neither the span not the input have margins at the top, there is no reason to create any space between this line box and the previous elements (or the top of the window).
Remember that the span does not have a fixed position on the screen to begin with. Its vertical spot in the line box can vary; same as if you had spans with a greater font size elsewhere in the line box.

Hope that clears things up!

So the solution to your original problem is simply to apply some top margin to the input. (Or, alternatively, to the span, but then you should also change its display to inline-block, as spans don't do margins by default.)